# Ipython Kernel Restart

Tags: python-2.7, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Well , I had this problem of Restarting kernel periodically so tried to upgrade ipython and successfully upgraded . But then now I am trying to open ipython notebook

> ipython notebook --pylab inline

So I am getting Following Error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/bin/ipython", line 9, in 
>       load_entry_point('ipython==2.2.0', 'console_scripts', 'ipython')()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-2.2.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/**init**.py", line 120, in start_ipython
>       return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-2.2.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/config/application.py", line 563, in launch_instance
>       app.initialize(argv)
>     File "", line 2, in initialize
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-2.2.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/config/application.py", line 92, in catch_config_error
>       return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-2.2.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 321, in initialize
>       super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)
>     File "", line 2, in initialize
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-2.2.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/config/application.py", line 92, in catch_config_error
>       return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-2.2.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/core/application.py", line 381, in initialize
>       self.parse_command_line(argv)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-2.2.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 316, in parse_command_line
>       return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)
>     File "", line 2, in parse_command_line
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-2.2.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/config/application.py", line 92, in catch_config_error
>       return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-2.2.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/config/application.py", line 475, in parse_command_line
>       return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)
>     File "", line 2, in initialize_subcommand
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-2.2.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/config/application.py", line 92, in catch_config_error
>       return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-2.2.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/config/application.py", line 406, in initialize_subcommand
>       subapp = import_item(subapp)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-2.2.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/utils/importstring.py", line 42, in import_item
>       module = **import**(package, fromlist=[obj])
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-2.2.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/html/notebookapp.py", line 60, in 
>       raise ImportError(msg + ", but you have %s" % tornado.version)
>   ImportError: The IPython Notebook requires tornado >= 3.1.0, but you have 2.3

So I tried To install tornado ,

> sudo pip install tornado

Its giving me following message

> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): tornado in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
>   Cleaning up...

What I understood is my python version isn't satisfying the requirements or I have two versions of python.. How to end everything to Latest version ?
The following is my OS details

> Linux mint 12.10, Quantal Quetzal

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade a python package with `pip` you have to [pass the `--upgrade` flag](https://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html?highlight=upgrade#cmdoption--upgrade). If you don't supply the flag then it will check whether your package is installed and, if it is, not do anything.

To upgrade `Tornado` you'd do

```
sudo pip install Tornado --upgrade
```

You can also try [installing IPython](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/install/install.html) with

pip install ipython[all]

which will install all dependencies, as opposed to just `pip install ipython`

Comment: Thanks For the reply I upgraded everything .
Still My ipython isnt working its giving me some infinite errors in my Terminal..
Everything Still pointing to python 2.7.3 .

Comment: Well python -V gives me Python 2.7.3..I dont know about another one . I think I have done some crappy  installs in sequence !

Comment: Yeah `python` will be Python 2.7.3, try `python3 -V` though.

Comment: @Hima if you want to continue this chat in the [Python chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) that might be better, rather than cluttering up comments. Up to you, I'll be in there anyway :)

Comment: Yeah Better Option it is !

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you install `tornado` with `apt-get install`, so you would get a older version, so you can update your `tornado` by type:

```
sudo pip install tornado --upgrade
```

And for `iPython` is update to `jupyter`, so you can type

```
sudo pip install jupyter
```

to enjoy the latest version.